# How to take the dict into .txt file, when my keys are tuple?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

How to take the `dict` into `.txt file`, when my keys are `tuple`?

When my keys are `int`, it can run successfully.

But when the keys are `tuple`, it fails.

```
dict = {(1, 1): 11, (2, 2): 22, (3, 3): 33, (4, 4): 44, (5, 5): 55, (6, 6): 66, (7, 7): 77, (8, 8): 88, (9, 9): 99}

import json
with open('dict.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(dict))

TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not tuple
```

Comment: You can't. As the error says json-keys are restriced to `str`, `int`, `float`, `bool` or `None`.
Do you have to use json?

Comment: The error is clear the keys of a JSON cannot be tuples, therefore you cannot use json.dumps to save to a file

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: Is there any other modules to write the dict into the text file?

Comment: Remove `import json` line and replace `json.dumps` with `str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your tuple to string before loading into json:

```
dict = {(1, 1): 11, (2, 2): 22, (3, 3): 33, (4, 4): 44, (5, 5): 55, (6, 6): 66, (7, 7): 77, (8, 8): 88, (9, 9): 99}

import json

def map_dict(d):
    return {str(k): v for k, v in d.items()}


with open('dict.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(map_dict(dict)))
```

Or you can directly convert dict to str:

```
dict = {(1, 1): 11, (2, 2): 22, (3, 3): 33, (4, 4): 44, (5, 5): 55, (6, 6): 66, (7, 7): 77, (8, 8): 88, (9, 9): 99}

with open('dict.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(dict))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the keys to strings.

```
new_dict = {}
for k,v in dict.items():
    new_dict[str(k)] = v
```

Then you could write the new_dict to the text file.